# Modern C++ for the Windows Runtime

Tags: c++11, uwp, wrl

I would like to build a C++ Univiersal Windows GUI app.
I would like to use C++11 only, not C++/CX,
 I downloaded [Modern C++ for the Windows Runtime](https://github.com/kennykerr/modern), but there is a only a simple application using xaml hard coded in the App::OnLaunched().
 Are there more complete examples, maybe like the UWP app templates found in VS2015?

Comment: Currently, the default/official way is to use C++/CX. In that repo, it created a C++ language projection for the Windows Runtime. if you need more help, I would suggest redirecting to its issue site https://github.com/kennykerr/modern/issues